# Randomly Selecting A Record From MySQL Through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I know that there's a lot of question in here that already solved that are about my question; however, I am trying to implement it through a link, and I can't seem to make it work.

I have a table named `tbData`, and columns within it that's named `firstName` & `lastName`; I am trying to select a random record off of it and I'm using the following code:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function randomfunction() {
            $.get("random.php");
            return false;
        }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<span style="color:#F0E6C3; font-size:30px; font-family: Trajan Pro;">                          
    <a href="#" onclick="randomfunction();">RANDOMIZER!</a>
</SPAN>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbPos");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

        $random = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbData order by RAND() LIMIT 1");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($random);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($random))
                    {
                      echo $row['firstName'];
                mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I'm trying to display the firstName and lastName as a string below the *RANDOMIZER!* link on my HTML file, but upon clicking it, nothing happens; am I missing something?

Comment: Some suggestions, Add print statements for debugging in your function start and end for both JS and php code. See if you are reaching till end.

Second catch and print exceptions if any.

Comment: check this line `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($random))`. you have used `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: Nah; actually that would work, since by default mysql_fetch_array returns both associative and non-associative http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: @mlg : thanks for this very useful link.but you are not getting my point here. he has used mysqli for connection and query and then he has used mysql_fetch_array for getting result array. FYI :  default mysql_fetch_array returns both associative and non-associative(I KNOW THIS)

Comment: Agree with prakash, you cannot mysqli_fetch_array the return of the SQL request for after mysql_fetch_array in while statement, it make no sense.

Comment: @prakashtank good point!

Comment: I updated my answer your problem should now be solved http://stackoverflow.com/a/41373193/3155987

Comment: Just a note to say that `ORDER BY RAND` is about the worst thing you can do to a database in terms of performance -- your query will be slow. If you have more than a trivial number of records in the table, it will be very slow. If you try doing it in conjunction with a `JOIN`, it will be excruciatingly slow. If you have less than a few hundred records in the table, then sure, it'll be okay. If you expect to have more than that, then there are other solutions that will get you a random sort order without the performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since you limit 1 your mySQL request, remove your while { } and just `echo $row['firstName'];` should work

```
<?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbPos");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

       $random = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbData order by RAND() LIMIT 1");

       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($random);      
       echo $row['firstName'];
       mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

For the html/jquery part as following :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span style="color:#F0E6C3; font-size:30px; font-family: Trajan Pro;">                          
    <a href="#" class=randomizer>RANDOMIZER!</a>
</span>
<p class=result></p>
<script>
$(".randomizer").click(function(){
  $.get("random.php", function(data, status){
    $('.result').html(data);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you go.

Comment: You probably want to check if there is an entry at all.

Comment: My answer is base on what I can see, This is supposed to work if there is indeed something to retrieve on his mySQL table.

Comment: This works! However, I'm only getting the desired results when I run the actual PHP file; moving onwards with the HTML button, and the Javascript that I've created, how would I be able to retrieve the data on my PHP and print it on my HTML file?

Comment: See the answer of matt here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41373203/3155987 it should probably work for the javascript part (don't forget to vote up if my answer provided any help to your problem)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a call back in your `.$get()` as such:

```
$.get('random.php', (results) => {
   // results will equal $row['firstName'] now 
});
```

If you need both values, I'd recommend changing your echo to

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

And then use `JSON.parse(results)` in your get callback

Comment: I have a question about presenting the results that I'm getting on my PHP file; with your help, I'm now using:

 function randomfunction() {
   $.get('random.php', (results) => {
    JSON.parse(results)
   });
  return false;
 }

.. and whenever I'm clicking the button, it's not printing my results.

Comment: You should create an HTML element like <p id='results'></p> and then in your JS, do results = JSON.parse(results); $('#results').text(results.firstName+' ' + results.lastName);